# Add all elements in matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to add all the elements in a matrix. This is an example of my matrix (the actual matrix is bigger):

```
 m = matrix(c(528,479,538,603),nrow=2,ncol=2)
 m
                   A            B
male              528          538
female            479          603
```

I am trying to do:

```
 sum.elements = colSums(colSums(m))
```

but it gives the following error:

> Error in colSums(colSums(m)) :    'x' must be an array of at least two
>   dimensions

I have tried doing:

```
x = colSums(m)
sum.elements = x[1] + x[2]
```

but this would be very long when you have a 100-column matrix...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do `sum`.  It also has the option `na.rm` to remove the `NA` values.

```
 sum(m)
 #[1] 2148
```

In general, `sum` works for `vector`, `matrix` and `data.frame`

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(24)
 m1 <- matrix(sample(0:20, 5000*5000, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000)
 system.time(sum(m1))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.027   0.000   0.026 

 system.time(sum(colSums(m1)))
 # user  system elapsed 
 # 0.027   0.000   0.027 

 system.time(Reduce('+', m1))
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #25.977   0.644  26.673
```

Answer (score 4):

`Reduce` will work

```
 Reduce(`+`,m)
    [1] 2148
```

Comment: I thought `Reduce` would be faster, but it was a bit slower

Comment: Beware also the meaning of `Reduce`: see the difference between `Reduce("+",iris[,1:4])` and `sum(iris[,1:4])`.

Comment: @nicola That would be because it is a data.frame, right?

Comment: Thanks akrun for the comparison and nicola for additional difference.

Comment: @akrun Indeed. What `Reduce(fun,obj)` does is to evaluate `fun(obj[[1]],obj[[2]])`, takes the result and then calls `fun(res,obj[[3]])` and so on. What the various `obj[[i]]` are depends on what `obj` is.

Comment: @akrun, `Reduce` is inevitably going to be waay slower for any array of any substantive size.  You get the R -> C overhead as many times as there are elements - 1, where as with `sum` you just get it once.